# Is there a way to pass variable from SetUp to TearDown?

Tags: c#, multithreading, testing, concurrency, nunit

I have a stack with users.

```
    public class UserProvider
    {
        
        private static ConcurrentStack<IUser> usersConcurrentStack = new ConcurrentStack<IUser>(new List<IUser> { new User1(), new User2() });
        public static Semaphore semaphore = new Semaphore(2, 2);
        
        public static IUser GetUser()
        {
            semaphore.WaitOne();
            popped = usersConcurrentStack.TryPop(out IUser user);
            return user;
        }

        public static void ReturnUser(IUser user)
        {
            usersConcurrentStack.Push(user);
            semaphore.Release();
        }  
    }
```

I want my tests to pick up one free user and put it back after test.

```
        IUser user; // This part is wrong. This value is modified by other threads.
        
        [SetUp]
        public void Preconditions()
        {
            user = UserProvider.GetUser(); // Take user from stack
            loginPage.Login(user);
        }

        [Parallelizable]
        [Test]
        public void CatalogSearch()
        {
            //Some testing
        }

        ... a lot of parallel tests here

        [Parallelizable]
        [Test]
        public void AnotherTest()
        {
            //Some testing
        }

        [TearDown]
        public void TakeScreenshotIfTestFailed()
        {
            UserProvider.ReturnUser(user); //Put user back in stack
        }
```

The problem is that variable "IUser user" is modified by other threads and in teardown method I put back wrong value. How can I pass the same value which was in setup to teardown?

Comment: You don't show this, but I'm assuming that all of your tests operate on the same `UserProvider` instance? Doesn't the very act of doing per-test setup/teardown steps which mutate the `UserProvider` which is currently being tested by other tests cause race conditions?

Comment: I don't create instances of the class anywhere because the methods are all static. I need the user stack to be available to all tests that run in parallel. So that two tests do not use the same user. It seems that the problem is in the race condition, but I still have no idea how to remove it.

Comment: Right, but if your TearDown method is adding as user *at the same time* as a test method is doing a test, won't that screw something up?

Comment: Hmm. I didn't think about it. Declaring a variable inside each test is also not an option.

Comment: _" I need the user stack to be available to all tests that run in parallel."_ Doesn't your implementation ensure the exact opposite of that?

Comment: Why? All tests refer to one static object.

Comment: One static provider. Not a static set of identical Users. And having them Semaphored makes parallelization somewhat senseless, too. Ignoring the result of the TryPop method, I'd expect exceptions, too all over the place.

Comment: It's looking at lot to me like your tests aren't actually parallelizable...

Comment: It seems when i use [Parallelizable] for a fixture instead of methods all working as expected. Race condition is gone. But how to do it inside one fixture is still a question

Comment: adding `[ThreadStatic]` attribute to `static IUser user;` solved the issue